# git filter-branch: Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes

Tags: git, git-stash, git-filter-branch

I run this command

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "echo AAAAAAA" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

And get the following error

```
Proceeding with filter-branch...

Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

Previously, I ran

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

running

```
git status
```

shows me

```
Refresh index: 100% (107206/107206), done.
On branch master

It took 8.70 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What else is git expecting me to do?

---

**Update: trying git status**

steps:

command:

```
git stash
```

output

```
No local changes to save
```

command:

```
git stash drop
```

output

```
No stash entries found.
```

command:

```
git status
```

output

```
Refresh index: 100% (107206/107206), done.
On branch master
It took 8.39 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'

may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add

new files yourself (see 'git help status').

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

command:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "echo AAAAAAA" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

output

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history

     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an

     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'

     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the

     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,

     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.

Proceeding with filter-branch...
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

Comment: It looks like filter-branch was confused by a stale index, which `git status` fixed. Does the error persist now?

Comment: @torek, No, it does not help. please see my edit.

Comment: OK, that's definitely odd. The status and filter-branch commands *should* agree about whether there are modified files here.

Comment: @torek, this is very sad that `git filter-repo` runs with no problem but `git filter-branch` has problem. `git filter-repo` does not do the favors that `git filter-branch` does.

Comment: Well, filter-branch is being phased out (it seems that nobody's doing any maintenance on it any more), so if there's something you like about filter-branch that's *not* in filter-repo yet, you might want to request it for filter-repo now. Meanwhile if you can identify what's actually going wrong in filter-branch, maybe you can get the Git guys to take a fix despite the phase-out plan.

Comment: @torek, I want to run a python script on every commit to copy files from different folders somewhere else, does some operations on them and then commit them inside a different repo. It looks like my script runs all in the same commit via `filter-repo` while it was file in `filter-branch`.

Comment: I haven't actually used filter-repo. That does seem like something it should be able to do—by which I don't mean to claim that I think it *can* do it now; I don't know what it can do now. But, if it can't, that's something that would be reasonable to ask for, before filter-repo replaces filter-branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually find the problem root cause.

It seems that running `git filter-branch` in a network directory is not that robust. I copied the files to the local machine and could successfully run `git filter-branch` command.